# Apache - Ubuntu desktop edition 9.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, desktop

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80

Am getting this error while am accessing http://localhost/

- Apache,phpmyadmin and mysql running fine.
- Bugzilla3 also working fine

Need some help to change the listening port for bugzilla in this ubuntu desktop

Please am new to linux am not that much aware about commands or configuration
Please give some idea to change the listening ports and my httpd.conf file is empty.

Thanks,
Ramesh V

Answer (score 0):

you take a look at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` also `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you install all of the listed software?
You may google for "LAMP on Ubuntu 9.04".

Or, you may else view the logs and search for the detailed errors descriptions in it.

For example, type this:

$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Enter your password and then update page in your browser window, you can see error messages in the real time in yours terminal window with such tail command.

Also good commands for working with logs is "less" (or "more") and, of course, "grep" (for example, "grep error /var/log/apache2/error.log" show every string where you can see an "error" word).

Answer (score 0):

With that little information is difficult to provide an answer.

First, the httpd.conf it is empty by default on Ubuntu (at least on old version like 9), the config is in apache2.conf, ant the virtualhosts are defined in /etc/apache2/sites-available and th actives are in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

You should ckeck:

1. Check the apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log)
2. Is apache running?
3. Is there a default virtual host configured
4. Check that you have a line in "127.0.0.1  localhost" in /etc/hosts

whithout more information is difficult to provide a precise answer.